# How expensive is it to call the Garbage Collector manually?

Tags: xamarin.ios, garbage-collection, xamarin

I am optimizing my application regarding memory consumption and just found out that the GC (sgen) is very lazy from time to time, so it doesn't clean up all the stuff that has been disposed so far for a long time. I even don't know if that stuff would be collected at all, which is critical especially for all the pointers to the native ressources (UIImage and so on).

So I started calling the GC manually at some points within my application, for example when popping or dismissing a controller.

```
GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
```

I am aware of the fact that this takes some time to complete, but are there any other drawbacks I have to consider?

Comment: What about `IDisposable` and calling `Dispose()` at the right time - looks a lot cleaner to me!

Comment: I am doing this heavily, but it doesn't free up the memory immediately. What may be an issue of the special MonoTouch architecture, which runs garbage collected on top of the native Objective-C environment, which is reference counted.

Comment: `Dispose()` is made for just that - on Windows, .NET runs garbage collected on top of WinAPI which has manual memory management and COM+ which is reference counted. `Dispose()` is a way to tell the managed (Mono, .NET) object to release the unmanaged (iOS, Android, Windows) resources it holds. This does NOT immediately release the Mono-used memory, but it DOES release the native UIImage and friends

Comment: I will further profile it and do a comparison of behaviour with Instruments. Thanks so far.

Comment: Thanks Eugen, you were right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there are some other drawbacks.

Even if you call GC.Collect, you can not ensure that objects that you believe are gone, are actually gone.   There might be references to the objects that you can not see either from managed code or unmanaged code.

As far as the GC is concerned, objects like "UIImage" occupy only a handful of bytes, you might load a few thousand of those objects and consume megabytes worth of RAM, but as far as the GC knows that is only a few KB of data.

This is because the GC has no idea that those innocent UIImage objects actually point to a juggernaut block of memory in the unmanaged space.

This also happens on .NET.   There are certain precious resources that you should return to the owner as soon as you stop using them, and not depend on the GC to collect the objects, as the GC really has no idea how important cute little tiny objects might be.

These resources are typically images (they consume a lot of RAM), network connections (you have a finite number of those), database connections (sometimes you might be charged per connection), files (finite number of handles) and things like that.

Those implement the IDisposable interface, and you should call Dispose() as soon as you are done with them.

UIImage is one of those.  You need to actively call Dispose on those objects.

That said in Xamarin.iOS, everything that subclasses NSObject is an IDisposable.   This is the pattern that we adopted to forcefully give up on the ownership of an unmanaged resource, even if many of those resources are not very expensive (NSString, NSUrl and so on).

The best strategy is to run the profiler, and identify your fat, large objects, and make sure you dispose them early.

Comment: Hi Miguel, Thanks for your detailed answer. If only you knew what I have gone trough the last couple of weeks ... So I think I know the most things, my assumption that the manual call of GC.Collect() is speeding up the process was a misinterpretation of a profiling session with Instruments.